# iPhone crash reports

Tags: iphone, debugging, crash-reports

I want to implement something like what four square do when the application crashes it sends out the crash report to their developers. But I really do not know how this is achieved. Can someone please let me know how this works and the components needed to implement something like this.

I guess the iPhone stores the crash report internally so you need to access it and I read something about a dSYM file as well? I this all I need? How can you get access to the crash file to email it out?

Thanks a lot for any help you can give.

EDIT:: So flurry has been mentioned, is there anything else anyone can recommend to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much simpler and easier if you use some tools such as Flurry (flurry.com). They offers built-in crash report. For example, Flurry can catch uncaught exceptions and log it, and since it sends the log to their server, you can view it online just like the normal event analytics.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ill look into that service

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out Apsalar, which is another pretty robust iOS / Android analytics package. It used to be pretty expensive but is now free. It can be configured to do crash reports as well.

Comment: I have tried using apsar and while it does log my event I don't get any of the exception details like flurry does.